# Font problems iOS 5.0 vs 4.3

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I have an app that uses a few custom fonts. When the app runs in iOS 5 the fonts display correctly, but in 4.3 they do not, and system fonts are substituted. Also, I'm using NSAttributedStrings in on place to do rich text in a UILabel subClass. In iOS 5, the attributed string works fine, but in 4.3 the app crashes. The crash comes in a category on NSAttributedString in this method:

```
-(void)setFontName:(NSString*)fontName size:(CGFloat)size range:(NSRange)range {
    // kCTFontAttributeName
        // crashes on next line
    CTFontRef aFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)fontName, size, NULL);
    if (!aFont) return;
    [self removeAttribute:(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName range:range]; // Work around for Apple leak
    [self addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)aFont range:range];
    CFRelease(aFont);
}
```

Any ideas on what is screwing up my fonts in 4.3? I've done a quick test project using the same fonts and they work properly in 4.3.

Jk

Comment: Where specifically (which line) does the crash occur, and what is the ultimate cause of the crash (exception or signal)?

Comment: And the message printed with the crash is ...??

Comment: No crash message in console, just EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line commented in the code above // crashes on next line

Comment: CTFontCreateWithName() will blow up if you pass it NULL for a font name, so maybe it's a memory management issue outside the scope of this function and unrelated to Core Text.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks pe8ter, for the hint. Turns out I was using an incorrect string for HelveticNeue. iOS 5 was able to handle it, 4.3 not so much